# $\int_{0\leq v\leq 2\pi,-1\leq t\leq 1}f(at+\sqrt{1-t^2}(b\cos v+c\sin v))dtdv=2\pi\int_{-1}^{1}f(u\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2})du$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Suppose $a, b, c$ are given real numbers, such that all of them are not zero.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on $[-\sqrt{{a}^{2}+{b}^{2}+{c}^{2}},\sqrt{{a}^{2}+{b}^{2}+{c}^{2}}]$, prove that
$$\int_{0\leq v\leq 2\pi,-1\leq t\leq 1}f(at+\sqrt{1-t^2}(b\cos v+c\sin v))dtdv=2\pi\int_{-1}^{1}f(u\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2})du$$

I have noticed that $$LHS=\int_{0\leq v\leq 2\pi,-1\leq t\leq 1}f(at+\sqrt{1-t^2}\sqrt{{b}^{2}+{c}^{2}}\mathrm{sin}(v+\alpha ))dtdv$$
$$={\int }_{-1}^{1}({\int }_{0}^{2\pi }f(at+\sqrt{1-t^2}\sqrt{{b}^{2}+{c}^{2}}\mathrm{sin}\left(v+\alpha \right))dv)dt$$
(By Fubini's theorem)
$$={\int }_{-1}^{1}({\int }_{0}^{2\pi }f(at+\sqrt{1-t^2}\sqrt{{b}^{2}+{c}^{2}}\mathrm{sin}v)dv)dt$$
(Since $f(x+2\pi)=f(x)$)
But then what can be done to complete the proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting $t=\cos(u)$ then the given integral is a surface integral over the unit sphere:
$$\int_{v=0}^{2\pi}\int_{u=0}^{\pi}f(a\cos(u)+\sin(u)(b\cos v+c\sin v))\sin(u) dudv=\iint_S f(ax+by+cz)\,dS.$$
where $x=\cos(u)$, $y=\sin(u)\cos(v)$, $z=\sin(u)\sin(v)$, and $S=\{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$.

Finally, apply [Show that $\iint_F f(ax+by+cz)dS = 2 \pi \int_{-1}^1 f(u \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2})du$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1544935/surface-integral-proof)

In a few words, the integrals on both sides are surface integral over the unit sphere expressed in spherical coordinates, but on the right-side the axes are conveniently chosen.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice observation!